# Css sourceMappingURL doesnt work correct in Chrome 59.0.3071.115

Tags: css, google-chrome, webpack, sass, source-maps

I have a project that is packaged via webpack.
Css is generated from sass with sourceMap.

```
    devtool: 'source-map',
...
    loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract(
      'css-loader?sourceMap=true&minimize=true!' +
      'postcss-loader?sourceMap=true!' +
      'sass-loader?sourceMap=true'
    ),
```

`app.css.map` file successfully generated and `sourceMappingURL=app.css.map` placed in `app.css`.
I see that Chrome recognized .map file in "source tab" because "webpack://" structure exists.

[image: Chrome recognized .map file]

**But debugger does not used this .map for css**:

[[image: But debugger does not used this .map for css[2]]

After that I convert `app.css.map` file to base64 (via online service) and paste it into `app.css`

```
sourceMappingURL=data:application/json;charset=utf-8;base64,eyJ2ZXJz...
```

and all works fine!

[image: all works fine]

Totally:

1. .map is correct (because it works in base64 format)
2. Chrome detects `app.css.map` and get it successfully (because `webpack://` exists in `source` tab)

Why it doesnt work with "map in `app.css.map`" but **same map works** when it in base64 format? How to fix it?

**---- UPD 1 ----**

I've tested in other PC with same chrome and all works fine. I think some chrome settigns make this bug.

Comment: @Rob I havent fount solution but if you ask about map in base64 you can read mo there: https://github.com/thlorenz/inline-source-map

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug of the latest versions of chrome with `Live SASS` option.

I've sended bug report about it. Turn off `live sass` is temporary solution.

[How to enable/disable it.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37313017/enable-live-sass-devtools-experiment)