# Enable live sass edit in devtools?

Tags: google-chrome, sass, devtools, google-developer-tools

How can we enable live sass edit in devtools?

like this post

https://umaar.com/dev-tips/103-live-sass/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Enable live Sass DevTools experiment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37313017/enable-live-sass-devtools-experiment)

Comment: yes but this was for old version of chrome

Comment: I see the sass file in chrome dev tools, and it has a green icon since it has been added to the workspace, but when I edit the css rule it turns grey and the actual file isn't updated

Comment: @AbdelrahmanElAwadi did you manage to enable live edit ?